# Integral of $x^{-2}e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

This is the original problem.

> $$\int_2^1 \frac{x^2e^x - 2xe^x}{x^4}$$

**My attempt at breaking it down**
     $$\frac{x^2e^x}{x^4} - \frac{2xe^x}{x^4}$$
      $$x^{-2}e^x - 2x^{-3}e^x$$
      $$ \int_2^1 x^{-2}e^x\,dx - \int_2^1 2x^{-3}e^x\,dx$$
I want to focus on the first term.
$$\int_2^1 x^{-2}e^x\,dx$$

How do I do this?

The differential of $x^{-2}$ is $-2x^{-3}$

Comment: Observe that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{e^x}{x^2})=\frac{(x^2e^x-2xe^x)}{x^4}$

Comment: $e^x/x^2$ on its own doesn't have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Please verify that the edit is correct. In particular every time you said "from 2 to 1" I wrote $\int_2^1$. Also, please learn to format. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

The comments on your post already solve the problem, as the integrand looks like something resulting from the quotient rule. But you can also use integration by parts for a more methodical approach.
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^2e^x - 2xe^x}{x^4} dx = \int x^{-2}e^xdx - 2\int x^{-3}e^x dx
\end{align}
Now use integration by parts for the first part
\begin{align}
\int x^{-2}e^x dx = e^x x^{-2} - \int(-2x^{-3})e^x dx
\end{align}
Plugging this into the first equation yields
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^2e^x - 2xe^x}{x^4} dx &= \int x^{-2}e^xdx - 2\int x^{-3}e^x dx\\
&= e^x x^{-2} - \int(-2x^{-3})e^x dx - 2\int x^{-3}e^x dx\\
&= \frac{e^x}{x^2} + 2\int x^{-3}e^xdx - 2\int x^{-3} e^xdx\\
&= \frac{e^x}{x^2}
\end{align}
This solves the indefinite integral which you can use to evaluate the definite integral.